# Sports self-evaluation: let's get critical!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, quality-evaluation

You love your site and we love your site, but there is a whole world of people out there who might not even know it exists. When they do find it, their first impression will either scare them away or keep them around. Given this, let's take a hard look at the questions and answers here and make sure newcomers see the site at its best!

Below you'll find ten questions randomly selected from this site. What do you think about each of them and their answers? Are they the best they can be or can they be improved? Would they look interesting and inviting to an outsider or are they a little embarrassing?

Upvote the corresponding post here on meta when we're awesome. Downvote when our content just isn't quite up to par.

Oh, and do comment to let everyone know your thoughts and take part in this conversation. :)

---

**This evaluation closed on May 31, 2012.**

Comment: After determining this, what can we do to fix it?

Comment: @Dynamic There are some basic things that are easy to do - edit posts to make them better, research and provide better answers or improve existing ones, close questions that cannot be salvaged, etc. Beyond that, if there's a problematic pattern (for example, a subject area that could be off-topic), you could open a meta discussion and see about adjusting the site policy accordingly. Does that help?

Comment: Yes. Thanks! I think Sports.SE would hate to see their site go...

Comment: I think this site has real potential.  I've added my comments regarding the questions below.

Comment: To the general public: If you vote on an answer in this question, **please go ahead and vote on the actual question and answers that it links to.** Good content should be rewarded and bad content should get negative feedback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you everyone for casting your votes and leaving your comments. :)

Here are some of mine:

While there are some issues with traffic and user retention, the biggest problem I can see right now in this evaluation are the types of questions and answers you're putting forth.

On a site with a [wide scope](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/a/162/73), you're ending up with easy questions that are answerable with a simple quote from Wikipedia or a rulebook. That's not necessarily a bad thing, but we don't want to just reprint stuff from other sites. There's not much point to that.

Focus on writing up comprehensive, well-rounded answers where possible. Questions like [this](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/673/help-recover-during-long-runs) or [this](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/623/why-5-runs-are-offered-if-ball-hits-the-helmet) could benefit greatly from that.

If you're asking a question, make it one that requires more than just looking up some information in a rulebook. Ask questions that solve problems and require expertise to answer.

Answer (score 10):

[Can referees change their decision?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/669/what-happens-if-a-player-scores-using-hands-and-referee-doesnt-notice)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: +1 Great question, community comments and a high-scoring authorative answer.

Answer (score 3):

[Calculations of bat speed and pace of a delivery](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/609/calculations-of-bat-speed-and-pace-of-a-delivery)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: This is a good, constructive question. I would like to see it's answer have a bit more detail though.

Comment: +1 for the question.  I agree that the answers need more substance.

Answer (score 3):

[Why do players enter with children on the ground?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/663/why-do-players-enter-with-children-on-the-ground)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: This is not a question that can be reasonably answered. It is basically asking a question, that may have 20 different answers, but accepting one of the possibilities.

Comment: +1 I actually like this question. I imagine a lot of people who see football very rarely might ask this question.  Also if you ask most people who attend football regularly this question, they'd say "They're mascots".

Comment: I think this question actually works pretty well.

Answer (score 3):

[In college sports, why is permission needed to recruit other coaches?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/620/in-college-sports-why-is-permission-needed-to-recruit-other-coaches)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Answer (score 1):

[Learning ski jumping](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/611/learning-ski-jumping)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: This is an iffy question in my book. I really think we have to get our FAQ down pat.

Comment: decent question with one meh and answer one answer that should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

[Help Recover During Long Runs](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/673/help-recover-during-long-runs)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: This one seems a little shallow

Comment: No up or downvote for me.  I think it's a bit too broad in its current state though. It should be more like: "What can I do in run preparation to prevent muscle ache" or "..to prevent general tiredness" or "..to improve post-run mobility".  Something more specific I think.

Comment: it might have been poorly formulated but I think it's a legit question.

Answer (score -2):

[How are the number of laps in an F1 race determined?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/629/how-are-the-number-of-laps-in-an-f1-race-determined)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: The answer was simply a quote from the rule book, which means it could have easily been "Google-ed".

Comment: I'm rather unsure about this one.  Yes, it's a google-able answer but then technically so is [What is the offside rule?](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3/how-is-offside-determined-in-soccer) Is one of our aims not perhaps to have that answer as the first google result?  As I say, I'm unsure right now.

Comment: @Dynamic, just because its a quote doesn't mean its easy to find. The top result is Wikipedia, where I can't find something like "number of laps".

Answer (score -3):

[Are there any Oval Track races in Europe?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/632/are-there-any-oval-track-races-in-europe)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Not so much that the answers are wrong, but "Are there any" invites simple yes or no answers. A more interesting reason would be why Europe doesn't have a lot of these tracks, which is probably because we prefer F1 vs Nascar

Comment: @IvoFlipse - I agree.

Comment: @IvoFlipse: +1 could not have said better

Answer (score -3):

[Why are 5 runs awarded if the ball hits the helmet?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/623/why-5-runs-are-offered-if-ball-hits-the-helmet)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Its a bit obvious that its a penalty, you'd hope/expect that the answers explained why its 5 and not 1 or 3

Comment: -1 The questions and answers need *much* more substance.

Answer (score -3):

[How to ollie on a skateboard?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/640/how-to-ollie-on-a-skateboard)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: It looks like the OP put no effort into research whatsoever.

Comment: -1 The asker should really be saying something along the lines of "How do you do an ollie on a skateboard?  **I've tried** following this tutorial but I'm having trouble getting height"... or similar.

Comment: bad question, but the answer redeems it...IMO :)

Comment: @waxeagle - any bias in that opinion?  ;o)

Comment: @Ste none at all ;)