# Determining our scope

Tags: discussion, scope

Sports.SE could be a great site. Think about it: athletes from all over the world coming here to learn more about their sport, and asking questions about how they can make themselves better. Or fans of a certain sport clarifying on the rules, making sure they're team didn't just get cheated.

So what can we do to build our site faster? We need to clarify our scope.

In this post, I want to see what the community thinks should be allowed on our site. After establishing this, we and the moderators can make edits to the FAQ, and begin enforcing our scope on questions.

I'm going to set a deadline: June 3, 00:01 UTC. After that, I wouldn't mind if the mods closed this as a duplicate or too localized. But until then, please do not close this question. It will only help the site.

Comment: look we've been over the scope issue like 8 times since private beta, what we need is good questions and answers, damn the scope.

Comment: @waxeagle Well, we have to get it down...

Comment: I think scope will be almost self-defining as the site grows and we have meta discussions.  I think we'll *just know* when we can document our scope.

Answer (score 5):

Our scope is sports.

Pretty much every aspect, from participation to fandom is on topic. Things that are related to sports, but might be on topic elsewhere (like fitness, or outdoors) are mostly on topic here unless they are squarely in the camp of those sites.

- General fitness is off topic, but running is on topic.
- General Outdoors question are off topic, but any competitive or recreational aspect that is on topic for that site is on topic. (snowboarding, skiing, surfing etc regardless of whether it's for competition)
- Martial Arts is completely on topic

Yes, our scope is broad, but at this point I don't think its poorly defined.

Comment: I especially like your second last line - MA should really end up being folded back in to this site, IMO. Still unsure as to motorsport...

Comment: The comment above this one is what I'm worried about. Why don't we know if motorsports are on-topic? There are also a lot of easily googled questions that're being asked and are not being closed.

Comment: @Dynamic so get the rep to cast close votes. As far as our scope is concerned, we are at a point where questions should be evaluated on their own merits and if we have to make some tweaks we do it. But those questions can be raised on meta individually without rehashing the first few weeks of public beta. (Look back, there are some epic discussions about our scope from those early days).

Answer (score 2):

[Our scope is sports](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/a/162/527). Here is a **non-inclusive** list of example topics:

- **Rule clarifications**

  *[How is offside determined in soccer?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3/how-is-offside-determined-in-soccer)*

  *[What's the rule governing the Lynch touchdown in the Falcons - Seahawks game playoff game?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2082/whats-the-rule-governing-the-lynch-touchdown-in-the-falcons-seahawks-game-pla)*
- **How-tos**

  *[How can I improve my ball handling?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/941/how-can-i-improve-my-ball-handling)*

  *[Achieving the optimal strike in squash: Is the wrist involved at all?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/614/achieving-the-optimal-strike-in-squash-is-the-wrist-involved-at-all)*
- **Equipment purpose/usage**

  *[What kind of shoes are suitable for a Novice/Sprint triathlon?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/1851/what-kind-of-shoes-are-suitable-for-a-novice-sprint-triathlon)*

  *[Why are there dimples on the surface of golf balls and how do they function?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/why-are-there-dimples-on-the-surface-of-golf-balls-and-how-do-they-function)*
- **Sports History**

  *[Which athletes were the first to break the color barriers in hockey?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/1490/which-athletes-were-the-first-to-break-the-color-barriers-in-hockey)*

  *[Which Olympic sport was the first to have a women's counterpart?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/1672/which-olympic-sport-was-the-first-to-have-a-womens-counterpart)*
- **Broadcasting**

  *[What is the broadcast etiquette when a pitcher has a perfect game?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/780/what-is-the-broadcast-etiquette-when-a-pitcher-has-a-perfect-game)*

  *[Why Cricket commentators read out score after every over?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2142/why-cricket-commentators-read-out-score-after-every-over)*
- **Theories and explanations of sports phenomena**

  *[What factors give a "Home Advantage" and how big is it?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/163/what-factors-give-a-home-advantage-and-how-big-is-it)*

  *[Does icing a fieldgoal kicker actually work?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/106/does-icing-a-fieldgoal-kicker-actually-work)*