# Are questions about "Mick Jagger's jinx" on the teams he supports on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, scope, asking-questions

Rolling Stones member Mick Jagger is infamous in sports world for being a kind of "unlucky charm" in soccer - when he supports a team, [it usually loses](https://www.reddit.com/r/soccer/comments/8y8fy2/the_story_so_far_of_the_mick_jagger_jinx/). I'm not sure if questions about this "curse" in sports would be considered on-topic here.

So, could I ask questions about the history of Mick Jagger's "jinx" here?

P.s.: of course I'm not suggesting this is a real, supernatural phenomena! But I'm interested in the cultural and statistic aspects of it.

Answer (score 3):

You can name it a fandom question, but even if the question will be about the statistical aspect of the curse, essentially, it will be looking for:

- Which games Mick Jagger has attended
- Which team Mick Jagger was supporting in these particular games?

And these 2 questions don't really lie within our [scope](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156/determining-our-scope/332#332). I think it's off-topic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was curious about exceptions to the rule (games which he attended but the team won), since I was not able to found them searching on web), so it would be essentially your example.

Comment: Thanks for discussing on meta before posting.