# Are questions on sports commentary on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, scope

I guess most commentary questions would be off topic, since they are not technically 'sport'. But I am not sure. Are questions on sports commentary allowed?

Comment: If you do want to check if a specific question would be on-topic before posting, hop into [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2433/the-clubhouse) (it's not very active, so feel free to tag me).

Answer (score 4):

I would say they are on-topic as a general subject; the [example list of questions which are on-topic here](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/a/332/6126) (8 years old now, but I don't believe the consensus has significantly changed) includes "broadcasting" and two questions specifically about commentary.

Usual disclaimer here: being on-topic as a general subject does not mean that all questions about commentary are on-topic. "Who's the best soccer commentator?" is as off-topic as "Who's the best soccer player?", but that is because it's opinion based, not because it is about commentary.